# How can I store a reference to a set of static Java methods from Scala?

Tags: scala, static, singleton, scala-java-interop

In the context of Eclipse Databinding, there are quite a few Java classes that act as factories for `IObservable` objects. For instance, there's `BeanObservables`, `PojoObservables`, `EMFObservables`, etc., and they all implement a set of methods similar to

```
  public static IObservableValue observeValue(Object target, String property)
```

Now if we were in the Scala world, each of those factories would probably be a singleton object implementing a common trait, say, `IObservableFactory`, and I could, for instance, pass them around as implicit values to methods that would use them to create data bindings.

But as they are defined in Java, it seems I can do none of that. I can't write

```
val pojoObservableFact = PojoObservables
```

because `PojoObservables` is not recognized as being a value.

Is there any way to make the compiler "instantiate" a singleton that would correspond to the `PojoObservables` class in Scala? Or any workaround for it? I know I could write the singleton myself and forward all method calls, but this sounds a bit tedious.

---

**Edit**

To make it clearer: this is what I'm trying to do: define a method that creates the observable value using a passed factory.

```
def createObservable(fact: ObservableFactory, target: AnyRef, property: String) =
  fact.observeValue(target, property)
```

but I wouldn't know how to define `ObservableFactory` or how to actually pass `PojoObservables`, a Java class with only static methods, to this `createObservable` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no-one else comes up with a working answer, I don't think it would be all that hard to write a code generator based on the method signatures.

```
val a = classOf[String].getMethods.map(_.toString).filter(s =>
  s.contains("public") && s.contains("static")
)
```

will, for instance, pull out all the method signatures (for `String` in this case) as strings.  Then

```
val b = a.map(_.split(" ").reverse.take(2).reverse)
```

will grab just the function signature with the return type split out front.  Now

```
val c = b.map(_(1).dropWhile(_ != '(').drop(1).takeWhile(_ != ')').split(","))
val d = b.map(_(1).takeWhile(_ != '('))
```

will get the argument signatures and name of the function, respectively.  We then need to convert the primitive types, which is pretty easy since we just need to capitalize the first letter (save for void which becomes unit):

```
def jprim2scala(s: String) = {
  val prim = List("boolean","byte","short","char","int","long","float","double")
  def arrayconvert(s: String): String = {
    if (s.endsWith("[]")) "Array["+arrayconvert(s.substring(0,s.length-2))+"]"
    else if (s=="void") "Unit"
    else if (prim contains s) {
      s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase + s.substring(1)
    }
    else s
  }
  arrayconvert(s)
}

def e = (b,c).zipped.map((bi,ci) => (jprim2scala(bi(0)), ci.map(jprim2scala)))
```

and finally you can put it all back together:

```
val f = (d,e).zipped.map((name,ei) => {
  val (ret,args) = ei
  val lastname = name.split('.').last
  "def "+lastname+"(" +
  (for ((a,i) <- args.zipWithIndex) yield ("a"+i+": "+a)).mkString(", ") +
  "): "+ret+" = "+name+"("+(0 until args.length).map("a"+_).mkString(",")+")"
})
```

Now you have a bunch of Scala code that you can put (by hand) in an appropriate singleton.

```
object Stringleton {
  // The contents of this is cut-and-paste f.map("  "+_).foreach(println)
  def valueOf(a0: java.lang.Object): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Array[Char]): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Array[Char], a1: Int, a2: Int): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0,a1,a2)
  def valueOf(a0: Boolean): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Char): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Int): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Long): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Float): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def valueOf(a0: Double): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.valueOf(a0)
  def copyValueOf(a0: Array[Char], a1: Int, a2: Int): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.copyValueOf(a0,a1,a2)
  def copyValueOf(a0: Array[Char]): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.copyValueOf(a0)
  def format(a0: java.lang.String, a1: Array[java.lang.Object]): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.format(a0,a1)
  def format(a0: java.util.Locale, a1: java.lang.String, a2: Array[java.lang.Object]): java.lang.String = java.lang.String.format(a0,a1,a2)
}
```

(Varargs aren't working here, incidentally--you'd need to fix those if they were present.  You can do this by going back to the `.isVarArgs` method from the method itself (not its string representation) and converting the last Array[X] into X* and then calling it as `ai: _*`.)

The nice thing about this approach is that if there are common methods, you don't even need to use structural typing in order to pull them out--you can define your own trait that your wrapped methods inherit from!  (And if you're especially ambitious, you can shoehorn almost-but-not-quite conforming methods to actually conform, e.g. to all have the same method name.)

Comment: For lack of working answer to the original question, I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply passing the factory method (or a set of methods, if needed)?

```
def createObservable(fact: (AnyRef, String) => IObservableValue, 
target: AnyRef, property: String) = fact(target, property)

createObservable(BeanObservables.createObservable, target, property)
```

Comment: Nice idea. Thing is, there is about a dozen factory methods I'm interested in… But this would certainly be a nice solution for a simpler case.

Answer (score 0):

So taking the reference for `PojoObservables` from [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3FePmVGdtrUJ%3ahelp.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/beans/PojoObservables.html+PojoObservables&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu&source=www.google.co.uk), I can see the static method `observeValue` as you describe.

This is an easy one, Scala treats static methods on Java classes as though they were defined on a companion.  You can either use this as though it were old-school Java:

```
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.PojoObservables
...
val ov = PojoObservables.observeValue(target, property)
```

Or the new-school variant with static imports:

```
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.PojoObservables._
...
val ov = observeValue(target, property)
```

You can then pass any such method around as a function object.  The idea that a function somehow needs to be escorted by its interface is very [Java-centric thinking](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html), just reference whatever you need and supply as an argument to other higher-kinded functions :)

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I can do this. However, I want to somehow assign `PojoObservables` to an implicit val, or pass it as parameter to a method which would then call observeValue, just as if it was actually a Scala singleton `object`.

Comment: I have to ask, but why?  In the absence of a common interface and other possible instances, what does an implicit gain you over and above a simple wildcard import of all the methods?

Comment: I'd use structural typing to "give" them a common interface. I want a mechanism that always returns the "right kind" of `IObservable`: as created with `EMFObservables` if they are EMF objects; as created with `BeanObservables` if they have property change support; etc.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use reflection:

```
object PojoObservables

val pojoObservableFact = PojoObservables.getClass.getConstructor()
pojoObservableFact.setAccessible(true)
pojoObservableFact.newInstance()
```

Now we can call the methods on PojoObservables.method...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. First, `PojoObservables` is defined in Java, not Scala. Second, calling `newInstance()` on the Constructor returns an object of type `PojoObservables`, but I still cannot call any of the static methods — which are the ones I'm interested in. Did you really get this to work?

Comment: You seem to be answering the opposite question--how to get a singleton instance from Scala loaded as if you were in Java (or how to get a second copy of a Scala singleton).

Comment: you should not try to use pojoObservableFact variable but rather object PojoObservables directly it will hold the ref to the singleton

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see what you mean. If you declare `object PojoObservables`, then there's no way to reassign it with anything else, and calling the constructor without even assigning the result to something doesn't look to me like it's going to help... Is it?